# Evaluation of find ( -exec )

Tags: shell, scripting, find

I'm searching for all files that contain one of a set of strings. If they do, I change their access rights.

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -q '#!/bin/bash\|#!/usr/bin/grep\|#!/usr/bin/awk' {} \; -exec chmod 700 {} ;\
```

I'm curious how the find works when it finds a file containing that string `grep -q` gives me `0` so another exec executes but should not. That second `exec` finds all files and change the rights to all files. Why does it work and change only those files containing that string?

Comment: @mnille if you are going to edit a post for formatting anyway, please read through the whole and fix the (many) other issues as well.

Comment: BTW, you might want to try it with this grep command instead: `... -exec grep -E -q '#! *(/usr)?(/local)?/bin/([bd]ash|[zk]sh|t?csh|awk|sed|perl)' ...`    (note: I removed the pattern that matches `/usr/bin/grep` because that makes no sense, grep is not a scripting language.  Added dash, zsh, ksh, tcsh/csh, sed and perl instead).

Comment: @cas why not just search for shebangs in general? Presumably, the OP wants to find all script files. Searching for `#!` makes more sense than trying to guess  al possible interpreters.

Comment: um, yeah. duh. that makes more sense.  also worth making sure that the `#!` is both at the start of the line, AND is the first line of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what your intention is (you didn't make that clear), but if it's to chmod to 700 all the files that match the pattern, then, except for your typo (`;\` instead of `\;`), your command seems to work as intended.

However:

> when it finds a file containing that string `grep -q` gives me `0` so another exec executes but should not.

Yes, it should do. 0 means success means true, so `find` continues to evaluate its expression, and the second `-exec` runs. 1 (or any value other than 0) would mean failure would mean false, so `find` would short-circuit its evaluation (there is an implicit logical AND between juxtaposed expressions) so the second `-exec` does not run.

> Why does it work

Check the manpage for GNU `find`:

> *expr1* *expr2*
>
> Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an  implied
>     "and"; *expr2* is not evaluated if *expr1* is false.